# MySQL query with multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql

I have a table **wp_postmeta** with columns called **meta_key** and **meta_value**. I have 5 records in **meta_key** (location,area,price,bedrooms,bathrooms)

[image: screenshot of table here]

For example, I want to find a hotel in Texas with 2 bathrooms:

```
select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'location' and meta_value = 'texas' and where meta_key = 'bathrooms' and meta_value= '2';
```

I know the above SQL command is not valid. Can anyone please help me to achieve the above result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try mysql subquery:

```
select post_id 
from wp_postmeta 
where meta_key = 'location' and meta_value = 'texas' 
                  and post_id IN (select post_id 
                  from wp_postmeta 
                  where meta_key = 'bathrooms' and meta_value= '2')
```

Comment: awesome its working... but i did small correction it should be select post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'location' and meta_value = 'texas' and post_id IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta where  meta_key = 'bathrooms' and meta_value= '2'), rest works like charm, thanks alot :)